# How to link to the root of an area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

In asp.net mvc 3, If I have an area called MyArea, how would I use Url.Action or Url.RouteUrl to get a link to `http://myapproot/MyArea/`? I want to link to the area's root so I can re-use the URL in javascript, so I don't want to have a controller or action in the url if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a "root" for your MyArea, you could create a route in the `RegisterArea()` method that is located in your MyArea's AreaRegistration class.

**Example:**
Foo is the name of the "root" controller..

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "MyArea/Foo/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Then from your Razor pages you can call the specific route like this...

```
@Url.RouteUrl("MyArea_default")
```

Which will be rendered as

```
/MyArea/Foo
```

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to *cleanly* write a link that goes just to /MyArea?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by _cleanly write_ - In my opinion calling @Url.RouteUrl("[route name]") is clean. Maybe you will prefer adding a new route to your **Global.asax.cs** which will simply specify "MyArea" as the URL. Then you can call **@Url.RouteUrl("MyArea")** on your razor pages to have **/MyArea** rendered.

Comment: Sorry, by 'cleanly' I meant basically achieving the same effect as creating a route specifically for the area, as you mention. So that would be the answer.  
  
The reasoning here is that I have a bunch of partial views stored in an area called 'Components', and I'm rendering them dynamically from ajax calls using depending on user actions (button clicks, whatever). This is why I want a direct link to the 'root' area URL, so I can reference that and then append the controller/action as needed. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Html.ActionLink`:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Show Blog", "ShowBlog", "Blog", new { area = "blog" }, null) %>
```

`Blog` is your area. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx).

Comment: Right, my understanding is that would be how to link to an action in a specific area. My issue is that I don't want to link explicitly to the Blog controller or the ShowBlog action.

Comment: So you have to set a `MapRoute` in `Global.asax` for that then call it's name in your `Url.Action` function.